# Javascript - Cannot read property 'style' of null - Problem when using onclick to post text to a table

Tags: javascript, html, django, html-table, onclick

When I click on a list item 'Add' button, I'm using button.onclick to send that item's text to fill out a table on the same html page. However, I keep getting a "Cannot read property 'style' of null" in the console whenever I click an item. This was working fine until recently. Something changed...somewhere, but I can't figure out why it's returning this error suddenly.

Here's the Javascript

```
    function showPage(page) {
        document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(div => {
            div.style.display = 'none';
        })

        document.querySelector(`#${page}`).style.display = 'block';
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(button => {
            button.onclick = function() {
                showPage(this.dataset.page);
            }           
        });
    });


    function myFunction(txt) {
        var myTxt = txt;
        console.log(myTxt)
        
        if (txt.includes('QB')) {
            document.getElementById("id_QB").value = myTxt;
        }

        else if (txt.includes('RB')) {
            document.getElementById("id_RB1").value = myTxt;
        }

        else if (txt.includes('WR')) {
            document.getElementById("id_WR").value = myTxt;
        }

        else if (txt.includes('TE')) {
            document.getElementById("id_TE").value = myTxt;
        }

        else if (txt.includes('K')) {
            document.getElementById("id_K").value = myTxt;
        }
        
    }
    
</script>
```

Here's the html page which is displaying a django template (I've deleted the on-page script tags containing the Javascript above).

````
{% load static %}

{% block body %}


<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<table id="playerName">
{{ form.as_table }}
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"  >
</form>

<br>


{% for player_data in player_data %}
<li><p>Player ID: {{ player_data.player_id }}: {{ player_data.player_name }}, {{ player_data.team }}, {{ player_data.position }}</p></li> <button  onclick="myFunction('{{ player_data.player_name }} {{ player_data.position }}')">Add</button>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %} ```
````

Comment: seems `document.querySelector(\`#${page}\`)` is null - maybe because `showPage(this.dataset.page)` is undefined since there's no elements with `data-page="some-value"` in your code

Comment: in short, your buttons probable had `data-page="????"` and now they don't (where `????` is an `id` of some other element) - perhaps it was `<li id="{{ player_data.player_id }}"><p>Player ID: ....etc...</p></li><button data-page="{{ player_data.player_id }}" onclick="myFunction(...etc`

Comment: Thanks for your ideas @JaromandaX. I've been thinking about your last comment. I don't quite fully understand what you mean by "elements with some-value." I should add that the entire error message is "pickteam:54 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at showPage (pickteam:54)
    at HTMLButtonElement.button.onclick (pickteam:62)

Comment: Bizarrely, a few minutes ago it was all working again. I refreshed the page to see if this would replicate but the error message is back. It really is weird.